# How to add a chart that would display 2 values from single row as {X,Y}

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice, I have a table like this

```
Element,X,Y
name1,0,5
name2,1,2
name3,5,7
...
```

so, I would like a chart that displays dots at {0,5}, {1,2}, {5,7}

as I am trying to use `Scatter (XY)`, all the suggested templates display some rubbish..

I can only achieve what I am after, by selecting "Data series in rows" and then manually adjusting ranges for "X-axis" and "Y-axis" for each of the "series" (lines/rows) which is VERY tedious

Isn't there some template/option I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: basically, Scatter gives me almost exactly what I need when I select just the B and C columns. However, then I am losing "Element" name which I would like to be displayed either on the chart or on the tooltip of the dot

Comment: Yes this is correct. Now add the range from column A to the description of the ranges in the "Data Labels" field. To display the labels on the graph, right click on one of the displayed points and select [**"Insert Data Labels"**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/schart/01/04030000.html?DbPAR=CHART&HID=modules/schart/ui/tp_DataLabel/tp_DataLabel#bm_id3144511), format the labels (replace "values as numbers" with "categories")